# How to build Mapbox GL Native for work within native code in the Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I need build Mapbox GL Native for work only within a native code in the Android. Building with "make android" makes library only for Java code. Please help me.

**Update**

@cammace. Thank you for explanation. I need to work with Mapbox in a cross-platform code of the engine's core. And calls of methods from Java side must be to the my core.

Answer (score 1):

Hey could you better discuss your use case for building from source? It is generally not recommended unless you plan to contribute and in many cases you can use gradle instead. If you want to go the easy route heres the [guide to setting it up in your android project](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#gradle). Essentially it's as simple as:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.0.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

To build from source like you've requested, it should be done on either a mac or linux since there are a few dependancies required. [Heres the first document](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/INSTALL.md) that will guide you to getting things setup and is for mapbox-gl-native itself. Within [platform/android](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android) there's additional instructions and the contrubuting guides also cover some topics, ones for [linux](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/CONTRIBUTING_LINUX.md), the other, [OSX](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/CONTRIBUTING_OSX.md).

Hope this helps!